# Guessing game not working and not printing finish_game (Python)

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import time
secret_word = 'secret' or 'Secret'
y = 'yes'
n = 'no'

def try_again():
    input("Try again: ")
    if input(secret_word):
        finish_game()

def finish_game():
    print("Nice job! Try again?")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    input("Y/N")
    if input(y):
        new_game()
    
    if input(n):
        print("You can always try later!")

    else:
        print("Hmm.. Don't recognize that. Try doing Y/N.")

def new_game():
    print("Welcome to Guess the Word!")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("You have unlimited tries to guess a word!")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Ready?")
    time.sleep(1)
    input("Guess your word here: ")
    if input(secret_word):
        finish_game()


new_game()
```

Every time I run, I input my secret word and just get "secret" in return. After that, the game ends. Any help to make it print finish_game?

Comment: This is odd: `if input(secret_word)`. That is saying "Prompt the user, and the message you tell the user for the prompt is the value stored in the variable `secret_word`. Now test to see if that user inputted value is `True` or `False`." None of that makes much sense, right?

Comment: Instead you want to capture the user inputted value into a variable `userGuess = input("Guess your word here: ")`. Then you want to see if the user guess matches the secret word: `if userGuess == secret_word:`

Comment: Also, I doubt `secret_word = 'secret' or 'Secret'` on line 2 is doing what you think. It will simply set `secret_word` to the string `secret` and won't check for `Secret` (with a capital) again next time `secret_word` is used.

Comment: @JNevill, just convert the comment to an answer

Answer (score 0):

This answer will get past not finishing the game, so you can work on the remaining game logic.

```
import time

secret_word = 'secret' or 'Secret'
y = 'yes'
n = 'no'


def try_again():
    input("Try again: ")
    if input(secret_word):
        finish_game()


def finish_game():
    print("Nice job! Try again?")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    input("Y/N")
    if input(y):
        new_game()

    if input(n):
        print("You can always try later!")

    else:
        print("Hmm.. Don't recognize that. Try doing Y/N.")


def new_game():
    print("Welcome to Guess the Word!")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("You have unlimited tries to guess a word!")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Ready?")
    time.sleep(1)
    answer = input("Guess your word here: ")
    # if input(secret_word): # Replace with the following.
    if answer in ['secret', 'Secret']: # a list of acceptable
        # answers
        finish_game()
    else:
        finish_game()

new_game()
```